# Visual Studio Team Services -> Create work item from email

Tags: email, support-tracker

We're running Visual Studio Team Service (VSTS) and Office 365 (O365) and we have a bunch of stakeholders/product owners who won't bloody login to the portal and create work items for them selves... instead sending emails! I work almost exclusively on VSTS so it'd be nice for support/project discussion to end up there.

I've setup up a custom process in VSTS with a custom work item type:
[image: Support work item type]

I've looked at a couple of tools like Mail2Bug and TMO but was wondering about other people's experience with these(or others?).

Ideally the process would work like so:

- I set up a support@email.com address that this tool can scan
- A user emails the support address with a problem (or I CC this email (in reply) in when I'm emailed directly)
- This will create a custom Support Work Item (Not a Bug or User Story) on the VSO (potentially with options to insert the item in a particular state, on a certain board etc.)
- Bonus points for:

  1. Auto updating the work item with content from follow up email
  2. Closing the ticket via email

What do you use?